# Runtime error in c++. Relocation protocol version %d

Tags: c++, stack, protocols, relocation

Please help me with following problem of transforming expression of spoj [here is the link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/). It is giving runtime error.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int testcases;
    cin >> testcases;
    while(testcases-->0)
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout << s;
        stack<string> st;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(s.at(i)=='(')
                continue;
            else
                if(s.at(i)==')')
                {
                    string s2=st.top();
                    st.pop();
                    string expression=st.top();
                    st.pop();
                    string s1=st.top();
                    st.pop();
                    string tba=s1+s2+expression+"";
                    st.push(tba);
                    cout << tba << endl ;
                    }
            else
                st.push(s.at(i)+"");
                }

        string ss=st.top();
        cout << ss;
        }

    }
```

And the error coming is not understandable.
following is the error with input in first and second line.

```
1
(a+(b*c))
(a+(b*c))do relocation protocol version %d.
o relocation protocol version %d.
uery failed for %d bytes at address %p
udo relocation protocol version %d.
do relocation protocol version %d.
o relocation protocol version %d.
uery failed for %d bytes at address %pery failed for %d bytes at address %p
udo relocation protocol version %d.
do relocation protocol version %d.
o relocation protocol version %d.
uery failed for %d bytes at address %pery failed for %d bytes at address %p
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the expected output/input? Describe your problem as accurately as possible. Currently this question should probably be closed.

Comment: PROBLEM STATEMENT IS : http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/

Comment: Check your program for input test case `"()"`.  Also check these: What if stack is empty and you are trying to access `top()`? What will `top()` return on empty stack?

Comment: `s.at(i)+""` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've fallen victim to a Java-ism.

```
char ch = 'a';
string str = value + "";
```

does not make `string str` "a".

This is because `""` is not a `string`. It's actually a pointer to a constant character array, a `const char *`, and because it is a pointer, pointer arithmetic takes place.

`""` is some place in memory. Let's assume address 10000. `'a'` has a numerical value. Let's stick with ASCII and use 97. `value + "";` is telling the compiler to go to address 10000 + 97, and nobody knows what it will find at address 10097. But it is a `const char *`, and `string` has a constructor that will take a `const char *` and try to turn it into a `string`. Whatever happens to be at 10097 will be used to make that `string`. This could crash the program. It could also grab garbage from the land of the string literals, and this looks to be what's happening to OP.

Solution:

Construct a `string`.

```
string str(1, ch);
```

or in OP's case,

```
st.push(string(1, s.at(i)));
```

[Documentation on `string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) See constructor 2.

But watch out. You have a bunch of other logic errors [best resolved by using the debugging software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that almost certainly came with your development environment.

Comment: do you mean that if i do stack.push('a'+""), then this will be considered as stack.push(const char *) and it crashes the program. Right?

Comment: Not quite, @PatelParth . It's still `stack.push(string)`, but the `string` is made from `'a'+""` which is the wrong, and potentially fatal, `const char *`.